# Logout fragment not working properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I have 2 activities, one is for logging in via facebook and the other is a home activity. I have a navigation drawer in home activity, which contains an item called Logout. I want new users to login via the first activity, if they have already logged in, then go to home activity and on clicking logout in the navigation drawer of home activity, to logout and redirected to login activity.

Here is my login activity:

```
package com.pipipzz.simpleapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;

import java.util.Arrays;


public class NewLoginActivity extends Activity {

    public static CallbackManager callbackManager;
    public boolean signedIn;
    public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    //public ProfileTracker profileTracker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initialize SDK before setContentView(Layout ID)
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        signedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("signedin", false);
        if(signedIn) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(NewLoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            //finish();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_login);

        // Initialize layout button
        ImageView button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Call private method
                onFblogin();
            }
        });
    }

    private void onFblogin()
    {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        // Set permissions
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "user_photos", "public_profile"));

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Log.d("Login Result", "Success");
                        signedIn = true;
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("signedin", signedIn);
                        editor.apply();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(NewLoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        //finish();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.d("Login Result", "On cancel");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        Log.d("Login Result", error.toString());
                    }
                });

//        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
//            @Override
//            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile1) {
//                Log.e("oldProfile", profile.getName());
//            }
//        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //Intent intent = new Intent(NewLoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
        //startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

I am trying to use sharedprefrences to store the login status. Here is my home activity:

```
package com.pipipzz.simpleapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout;
    CharSequence Titles[] = {"Following", "Trending"};
    int numOfTabs = 2;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        //Initialise views
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        assert ab != null;

        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu);

        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, numOfTabs);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                //return Color.parseColor("#88ffffff");
                return Color.parseColor("#FAC80A");
            }
        });
        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#263238"));
        }

        FloatingActionButton button = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.ddd);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ImageGridActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Find our drawer view
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.menu);
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);


        // Find our drawer view
        NavigationView nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        // Setup drawer view
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });

    }


    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on
        // position
        Fragment fragment = null;

        Class fragmentClass;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
                fragmentClass = MyFeedFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
                fragmentClass = SurpriseMeFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
                fragmentClass = GalleriesFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_fourth_fragment:
                fragmentClass = MyProfileFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_fifth_fragment:
                fragmentClass = MessagesFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                fragmentClass = SettingsFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                fragmentClass = LogoutFragment.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = MyFeedFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        //setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }

//        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
//            return true;
//        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

I don't want to draw any UI when logout is clicked in navigation drawer, so I am creating a no UI fragment for logout:

```
package com.pipipzz.simpleapp;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class LogoutFragment extends Fragment {

    public LogoutFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        }
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        //editor.clear();
        editor.putBoolean("signedin", false);
        editor.apply();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewLoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

On doing above, I am able to logout of facebook, but I am not able to redirect to the login activity. I searched a lot, but couldn't find anything. What can be the problem? Please help.

Comment: Try changing `editor.apply()` to `editor.commit()`

Comment: It is not working. I think `editor.apply()` is same as `editor.commit()`. The only thing is, `editor.apply()` does it in a background thread instead of UI thread. The problem is that I am not able to start the intent and redirect to login activity after logout.

Comment: Do you have any LogCat output that you think could help?

Comment: There are no errors in LogCat. When I click logout on navigation drawer, the drawer closes and I am on the home activity itself.

Comment: Since the logout fragment is a no UI fragment, do I need to call it via string tag instead of id in the home activity?

Comment: can anyone suggest some fix, please?